# Time limit exceeded(TLE) Error in Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I'm trying a code on Hackerearth which is to Find special number. A number ***n*** is said to be special if the sum of its digits is divisible by 4
For a given integer ***a***, find a number  such that:
***n*** is a special number,
***n***>=***a***,
***n*** is minimum possible.
I have created a code with all my knowledge and working absolutely fine and giving correct input but it is giving Time limit exceeded error

```
def add(n):
    num_str = str(n)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(num_str)):
        sum += int(num_str[i])
    return sum
T=int(input())
while T>0:
    a = input()
    final=min([x for x in range(int(a),1006) if add(x)%4==0])
    print(final)
    T = T - 1
```

Comment: Where did 1006 come from?

Comment: Looks like you can short as soon as you've found the first special number? So instead of finding all special numbers between `a` and `1006` upfront, just increment `a` until you find a special number.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry for not informing in the question the special number is less than equal to 1000

Comment: @micah can i do it in range function ?

Comment: Just use a regular loop here. I will add as an answer but i think there is probably more to this problem. A link to the actual problem would be helpful

Comment: @micah are loops are faster than list comprehension ? because i have checked it before making code on google it says list comprehension are faster than loops

Comment: List comprehension is faster when you must do all of the work in the loop. But in this case you can **short circuit** as soon as you find a solution.

Comment: @micah this the link to actual problem [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/find-product/)

Comment: The linked problem isn't even close to what is described here.

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry for that actually I'm new here in this community and don't know much about please don't downgrade my question i will edit this plz

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is increment `a` and short as soon as you find a match. Currently you are calculating all of the possibilities before selecting out the lowest. All of that is unnecessary work when you just want the first match.

```
final = -1
for x in range(int(a), 1006):
  if add(x) % 4 == 0:
    final = x
    break
print(final)
```

Comment: Especially since the first match is no more than a+6.

Comment: @ScottHunter thankyou so much for this code removed my TLE exception but you need little correction break should come after print

Comment: (speaking in ScottHunter) Yeah no problem lmao

Comment: I didn't write this, but it looks like @micah put the `break` exactly where it needs to be (once the solution has been found, stop looking).

Comment: so sorry @ScottHunter my mistake but i have request can remove the downgrade

Comment: @RishavFounsa voting is anonymous. it may not have been scott who downvoted your question. It's also not the end of the world. Your question was downvoted likely because it was unclear. Just do better next time :)

Comment: @micah my bad 